# Can MariaDB's Maxscale(BinLog Server) be used as a collector of binlogs from different mysql clusters?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqlbinlog, binlog, maxscale

I have read that Maxscale(**BinLog Server**) of MariaDB can be used for relaying the bin logs from a MySQL Cluster to a single **BinLog Server**, however i wanted to know if its possible to collect all the bin logs from different MySQL Cluster and persist on a single **BinLog Server** and no mysql slaves would be reading from it. In case its possible how are the conflicts like same database name in different MySQL Cluster, etc are handled?

Answer (score 0):

The *binlogrouter* module in MaxScale is a replication proxy. It stores the binary logs of the master on the MaxScale server. Unlike a normal replication slave, the binlogrouter will not write its own binary log. This means that the binary logs on the MaxScale server will be identical to those on the original master server.

To collect binlogs from multiple clusters, you need to configure multiple binlogrouter services and point each one of them to a master server. The binary logs are stored separately for each configured service.

Here's an example configuration of a binlogrouter service and a listener:

```
[Replication-Router]
type=service
router=binlogrouter
version_string=10.0.17-log
router_options=server_id=4000,binlogdir=/var/lib/maxscale/,filestem=mysql-bin
user=maxuser
passwd=maxpwd

[Replication-Listener]
type=listener
service=Replication-Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=3306
```

Read the [Binlogrouter documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/5941/) for more information about the various options.